# C# casting String to DateTime

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I want to cast in C# a `String` to `DateTime`.

My String contains: `String input = "2012-07-31T00:00:00.000+0200"`

and i used the following pattern: `String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd%HH:mm:ss.fffz";`

```
MyDateTime myDate = new DateTime();
MyDateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(input, datePattern, null);
```

And i am getting the following error: `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Was pretty sure, because i am not sure how to solve this `'T'`and which Timezone i should use.
There are three variants of it at the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) side.

Which one i need to use, or can i create my own one?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`The "K" Custom Format Specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#KSpecifier) with `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFK"` format like;

```
string s = "2012-07-31T00:00:00.000+0200";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFFK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Output will be;

```
7/30/2012 10:00:00 PM
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/bqS83E)</kbd>.

For more information take a look at;

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)